# Что такое Getters and Setters?

Tags: java

Я новичок в Java и хочу разобраться с терминологией. Возможно я это уже применяю, но не знаю что оно именно так называется. Приведу пример как я понимаю, если я не прав, пожалуйста, поправьте. Пример геттера:

```
viod Sum(int a, int b){
    int s=a+b;
    return s;
}
```

Пример сеттера:

```
static void TxtHP(String name1, String name2){
    System.out.println(nameA1 + " любит " +name2); 
}
```

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то это не примеры геттера и сеттера. Сеттер получает значение и  присваивает его переменной, а геттер наоборот его отдаёт. Можно легко жить и без них, но есть мнение, что они делают код более надёжным, так как не позволяют на прямую манипулировать значениями переменных.

Comment: get - получать, set - размещать, устанавливать. Следует не только учить синтаксис языка Java, но также обязательно изучать английский язык и чем быстрее вы возьметесь за инглиш, тем лучше.

Comment: **setter** (Мутатор) - метод ля изменения значения поля объекта, _доступ к которому напрямую ограничен_ его областью видимости. **getter** (Акцесссор) - метод для получения значения поля объекта.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, геттеры и сеттеры имеют смысл, в основном, в контексте Java Beans.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Ставлю + за сеттер :) Никогда таких сеттеров не видел в своей практике.

Comment: вот тут детально и подробно расписано
[Геттеры и Сеттеры](https://vertex-academy.com/tutorials/ru/gettery-i-settery/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ваши примеры это совсем не то. Это не геттеры и не сеттеры - это вообще из другой планеты.

Геттер - это метод возвращающий значение некоего свойства класса, а сеттер соответственно то что устанавливает свойство класса. Пример:

```
public class MyClass {
   private String name; //свойство

   public String getName() { //геттер
      return this.name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) { //сеттер 
      this.name=name;
   }
}
```

Существует *naming convention* - соглашение об именовании, согласно которому геттер должен называться: `get<Свойство>()`, а сеттер `set<Свойство>`

**Update**

согласно указанному naming convention построены т.н. [Java Beans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans), а на этих бинах столько уже понаверчено, например [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) - так что именование здесь не простая блажь, а средство выживания.

**Update2**

Возвращаясь к вопросу *naming convention* для булевских свойств принято именование геттеров: `boolean is<свойство>()`, а не `boolean get<свойство>()`, кроме того существуют индексированные свойства (или свойства в виде массивов), для которых существуют 4 вида геттеров/сеттеров:

```
Foo[] getFoo();
Foo getFoo(int );
void setFoo(Foo[] );
void setFoo(int, Foo);
```

[Первоисточник](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf?AuthParam=1509708349_4ee2cd6226573ec0f6179f89b1e2e535)

Comment: спасибо всем огромное.

Comment: для boolean так же используется префикс has.. (как `hasFocus()`), в зависимости от результата, возвращаемого методом (is - является, has -имеет, содержит)

Answer (score 4):

getter позволяет получить значения (читать значения), а setter - записать значения в переменную.
В коде они представляют собой обычные методы. Но имя метода всегда начинается с префикса get или set.

```
class someClass(){
    private int a;

    public int getA(){
       return a;
    }

    public void setA(int a){
       this.a = a
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Getters и Setters это и есть один из китов ООП, а именно инкапсуляция. Их используют для получения доступа к закрытым свойствам. Почитайте [здесь](http://java-course.ru/begin/incapsulation/) для полноты понимания.